# Range slider - how to change tick color when it's filled?

Tags: javascript, css

See my code here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMQKdp

I'm trying to have one color for the tick when it's filled and different color when track is not filled yet.

Is this possible?
Exampled on the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u65F.jpg
How I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuxQH.jpg

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMQKdp

This is how I'm creating ticks:

```
#tickmarks p {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background: green;
    color: green;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 54px;
    top: -34px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare your `_R.value` with each innerHTML property of all `p` elements of your html, like following:

```js
const _R = document.querySelector('[type=range]');
_R.style.setProperty('--val', +_R.value);
_R.style.setProperty('--max', +_R.max);
_R.style.setProperty('--min', +_R.min);

document.documentElement.classList.add('js');

_R.addEventListener('input', e => {
  handleColors();
  _R.style.setProperty('--val', +_R.value);
}, false);

function handleColors() {
    var ticks = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for(let i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++) {
    if(parseFloat(ticks[i].innerHTML) < _R.value) {
      ticks[i].style.background = 'blue';
      ticks[i].style.color = 'blue';
    } else {
      ticks[i].style.background = 'green';
      ticks[i].style.color = 'green';

    }
  }
}

handleColors();
```

```css
input:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
    .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
        --ratio: calc((var(--val) - var(--min))/var(--range));
        --sx: calc(.5*1.5em + var(--ratio)*(100% - 1.5em));
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1.5em;
        background: transparent;
        font: 1em/1 arial, sans-serif;
        border: none;
    }
    .slider, .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        width: 12.5em;
        height: 0.5em;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .js .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        background: linear-gradient(#7b1c1a, #7b1c1a) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat #ccc;
    }
    .slider::-moz-range-track {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        height: 0.5em;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .slider::-ms-track {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        width: 12.5em;
        height: 0.5em;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .slider::-moz-range-progress {
        height: 0.5em;
        background: #7b1c1a;
    }
    .slider::-ms-fill-lower {
        height: 0.5em;
        background: #7b1c1a;
    }
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99;
        margin-top: -0.550em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        width: 1.5em;
        height: 1.5em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #7b1c1a;
    }
    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        width: 1.5em;
        height: 1.5em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #7b1c1a;
    }
    .slider::-ms-thumb {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99;
        margin-top: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        width: 1.5em;
        height: 1.5em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #7b1c1a;
    }
    .slider::-ms-tooltip {
        display: none;
    }
    #tickmarks {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    #tickmarks p {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        background: green;
        color: green;
        border-radius: 100%;
        line-height: 54px;
        top: -34px;
        left: 3px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="5" max="20" value="10" step='2.5' class="slider" id="myRange" list='tickmarks'>
    <div id="tickmarks">
        <p>5</p>
        <p>7.5</p>
        <p>10</p>
        <p>12.5</p>
        <p>15</p>
        <p>17.5</p>
        <p>20</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I needed

Comment: @noni great! you can either upvote this answer it you found this helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the tick yourself, but you could just set range: true, in your slider call in javascript, for example like this:

```
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  tooltip: 'always',

});
```

This will have a different color for the range than the main slider color If I understood your question.

Comment: Do I need to use some sort of library for this? I'm not using any range slider library at the moment.

Comment: Seems the other answer already worked for you, to answer your question no you do not need any library for it, pure javascript would do.